# What is best way to create express controller with promise.coroutine?

Tags: node.js, express, bluebird, es6-promise

I have following express controller:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var co = Promise.coroutine;

class MainController {
  constructor(env) {
    this.env = env;
  }

  index() {
    var self = this;
    return co(function*(req, res, next) {
        var trips = yield self.env.repo.trips.getTrips();
        var viewModel = new ViewModelBase(req, {layout: 'layout', trips: trips});
        res.render('index', viewModel);
    });
  }
}
```

I'm using this controller following way:

```
var mainController = new MainController(this.env);
router.get('/', mainController.index());
```

Is there way to make this code cleaner? 
Can I avoid var self = this; before each co-routine?
Where can I find best practice guide about usage es6 in express 4 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use promises without bluebird in node 4+ and arrow functions so maybe something like this...

```
//SERVICE

getTrips(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {  
    //TRIP LOGIC?
    resolve(tripData);
    //reject(error);
  });
}

//IN THE CONTROLLER
index(){
  getTrips(someData).then((results)=>{
       let viewModel = new ViewModelBase(req, {layout: 'layout', trips: results});
       res.render('index', viewModel);
    }).catch((error)){ //handle error });
}
```